# Matching Regex doesn´t work

Tags: php, regex

I have a string `$subDay` like this:

```
Checkin 03:35 OL 270 DRS-ZRH 04:25-05:45 HSC, KRG, LEM, JOA OL 271 ZRH-DRS 06:45-08:15 HSC, KRG, LEM, JOA Checkout 08:45
```

and I want to add a new line (\n) with this command:

```
$subDay = preg_replace("/(Checkin [12][0-9]:[12][0-9])/", "$1\n", $subDay);
```

I tested it with this [RegexTester](http://regexpal.com/) and my RegEx seems valid, but nothing happens.

Why?

Comment: I totally crushed it -.- I used the wrong regex for the time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i used this RegEx:

```
/(Checkin ([01]{1}[0-9]{1}|[2]{1}[0-3]):[0-5]{1}[0-9]{1})/
```

It only matches double-digit valid times.

Answer (score 4):

The character class `[12]` only matches 1 or 2. It does not match the 0 in `03:35`. Try this instead:

```
/(Checkin [012][0-9]:[0-5][0-9])/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/(Checkin [012]{1}[0-9]{1}:[0-5]{1}[0-9]{1})/
```

Could be improved, because at the moment it will match 29, but you can play with it further if you need

Comment: I improved the regex a little bit to only match correct times and postet it as answer